# What are the fonts used for this WWII Jolly Roger sign?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can anybody help me identify the fonts used here?

The sign is WWII, circa 1943 if that helps. I've been digging around for hours and I can't seem to get it.

Tried matching heavy on what the font - nothing is really close.

[image: 90th Bomb Group]

Comment: More than likely this is the work of a sign painter, who would have painted these letters by hand. There may or may not be an actual digital font based on these.

Comment: I agree with DA01, this was hand painted.  Analyze the three 'B' letters in the bottom two lines, all three are slightly different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, I didn't found the exact same font, but I think this is the most similar-looking fonts you can get:

For the upper part I would also go with Bell

and for the lower part: Legothic URW Light 
[image]

I would post an images, but I signed on a few days ago, so I'm not allowed to..

Comment: Have +1 for a good answer! Now you can load the image :-)

Comment: Wow that Legothic URW is a good find - very good match, even the lowercase "e".  Only slight differences like the "R" tail and the "W" middle stroke.

Comment: Yeah, and also the dot on the lowercase "i".. But as I said: It's as nearest as you can get..

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will be hand-lettering, meaning that it doesn't use a font and may not even be based on any particular typeface.  In this case, I don't believe it's based on any particular typeface but instead borrows from many.

The top one bears a resemblance to [**Bell**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/bell-mt/)

[image]

But then, it's about as similar to Bell as it is to [**Times**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/times-new-roman/).

I don't think the bottom one looks like anything in particular.  It's quite different, but [**Linotype Spitz**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/spitz/) may evoke a similar feeling.

[image]

*Edit: Marcel Lasaj's suggestion of Legothic URW for the bottom font is even better.*

Comment: Hey thanks for the recommendations! We were hoping that the sign painter used an “at-one-time commonplace stencil” that somebody might recognize.

Comment: Hey, Marcel Lasaj's suggestion of Legothic URW for the bottom font is even better than mine.

Comment: Unfortunately it is unlikely to have been based on a stencil.  Skilled sign-writers prided themselves on their hand-lettering ability.